# MGSplitViewController with all github patches?

Tags: ios, ipad, github, uisplitviewcontroller

I am interested in using MGSplitViewController but it seems that is has current bugs, especially when used in a tabbarController.  I see that there are quite a few submitted patches on github for this.  Is there a way to pull the files with all those patches?  Or does someone have a branch that they are updating with all the new patches?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article "[Quickly applying GitHub pull](http://effectif.com/git/applying-github-pull-requests) " details how to apply a pull request (which is at its core a patch)

See the [patch and apply section](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests#patch_and_apply) of the [Send Pull Request GitHub help](http://help.github.com/send-pull-requests/)

> Another approach that’s a bit quicker in one-off cases is to use **`git-am`**.
>
> Every pull request has a **`.patch` URL** where you can grab a textual patch file to feed into the `git-am` command:

In your case:

```
$ git checkout master
$ curl https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController/pull/43.patch | git am
$ git push origin master
```

Since you can [list pull requests through the GitHub api](http://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/), you can combine that in order to quickly apply all current pending pull requests.

Comment: You might want to make sure that the commit hashes are the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550400/should-git-apply-or-git-am-come-up-with-the-same-hash

Answer (score 1):

I created an [answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13976381/1904815).

I use [git-pull-request](https://github.com/splitbrain/git-pull-request) to get the list of open pull requests with `<number>`, `<user>` and `<branch>`.
This can also be gathered manually at the web page of every request.
Then I pull the corresponding github branches directly.

```
# pull request <number>
git pull https://github.com/<user>/MGSplitViewController <branch>
```

See [Merging a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests#merging-a-pull-request) from the github help.

---

I don't like applying patches with `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/pull/<number>.patch`when I have the repositories at hand.
Especially since commit hashes can change using `git am`, which would "mess up" the github network view.
See [should-git-apply-or-git-am-come-up-with-the-same-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550400/should-git-apply-or-git-am-come-up-with-the-same-hash)

Comment: Interesting more robust alternative to my answer. +1