# Getting my copy of a github project up to date

Tags: github

I want to use a github project (mgsplitviewcontroller). Unfortunately the owner does not appear to be accepting changes. There are several pull requests that I would love to merge in, but being new to github I can't figure it out.

What I would expect:

- I fork the project
- I review and inspect the pull requests from the original
- I merge in the pull requests that I want to accept

Forking is easy, but once I have done that, I can't get at the pull requests for the original.

I have read this answer on [how to apply the patches to my local copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614494/mgsplitviewcontroller-with-all-github-patches),  but it does not tell me how to get the URL's for the patches, and I can't seem to find that in the github site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `.patch` at the end of the pull request url on the original project.

For example, if the url for the pull request is `https://github.com/manojlds/Toggler/pull/1`, you can get the patch at `https://github.com/manojlds/Toggler/pull/1.patch`

Edit: The answer that you point to says the same. Just add the `.patch`, and pipe it into `git am`

Comment: OK. But there is 20 pull requests. Will I have to click on each of them to get the number it maps to? For example, the newest request appears to have number 78, which is definitely not in the range of 1-20 (or 0 to 19). I see that he links to some scrip that claims to do this, but that also references all kinds of stuff that I have no prior experience of (github api?).

Comment: @AndersSewerinJohansen You will have to get the pull request ids that you need by yourself. How can anyone tell you what you need?

Comment: @AndersSewerinJohansen This is more GitHub than git :)

Comment: You might want to make sure that the commit hashes are the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550400/should-git-apply-or-git-am-come-up-with-the-same-hash

Answer (score 1):

[git-pull-request](https://github.com/splitbrain/git-pull-request) is a tool that can list all open pull requests for a github repo.
This listing includes the actual `<user>:<branch>` that leads up to this pull request and the `<number>`.

You can feed this info to another script that extracts this information and creates a command line (or do this step manually):

```
# pull request <number>
git pull https://github.com/<user>/<repo> <branch>
```

You might not want to pull all requests automatically and just let the script print the command to be issued.
This way you can create a new branch locally, pull in one request, have a look what it actually does, make some fixes and only then merge this request to your master.

See also [Merging a pull request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550400/should-git-apply-or-git-am-come-up-with-the-same-hash) from the github help.

---

Another approach is using

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/pull/<number>.patch
```

after getting the relevant `<number>s` from `git-pull-request`.
In this case the `<user>` and `<repo>` are the same for every patch.
It's the user/repo you forked.

**Make sure that the commit hashes don't change.**
See [should-git-apply-or-git-am-come-up-with-the-same-hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550400/should-git-apply-or-git-am-come-up-with-the-same-hash) for how to avoid it.
This makes things easier when the original maintainer pulls these requests later on.
Additionally the github network graph will show your repository as having pulled these branches.

Comment: I personally don't see having an automatic list of pull requests as much of a help. I want to review every request (includes reading the comments) and decide if I really want to pull it anyways. Getting the information on which branch/repo to pull is easy in comparision to the review.